# has_many relation with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I have a Model (user) that has_many :bookings

bookings have a complete field

Id like to be able to view all the bookings for a user where the booking complete is true
I'd also like to be able to sometimes show all the bookings for a user regardless of complete

Whats the best way to set this up in my models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `complete` is a boolean value on `Bookings`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
end
class Bookings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :completed, where(complete: true)
end
@user.bookings.completed #Complete bookings
@user.bookings           #All bookings
```

Comment: Wow, i was expecting something much more complicated involving setting up an alternative has_many with conditions on it etc etc. rails is just amazing.  For the second day in a row, thank you kindly.

Comment: lol Yeah. Didn't realize I answered your question yesterday too. Glad I can help. Happy coding.

Comment: Scopes are surely a good method where possible but setting conditions on a secondary has_many is still required in some scenarios such as eager loading from a table you already joined to.  Such as finding all incomplete bookings of users with complete bookings (more or less): `User.joins(:bookings_completed).includes(:bookings_incomplete)`. So your thoughts were not that far off the mark and these are not that hard to set up either.